# Elementor custom widget's icon doesn't display

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, elementor

Now I am going a Wordpress lesson and do everything what teacher do on Youtube lesson. Just made custom widget in Elementor. But it is no icon in it.

[image: Here is a pic]

Here is a code inside of Widget. What I don't understand?

```
/**
 * Get widget icon.
 *
 * Retrieve About widget icon.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @access public
 *
 * @return string Widget icon.
 */
public function get_icon() {
    return 'fa fa-code';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured out that such class as was in default `"fa fa-code"` doesn't work in Elementor. For Elementor works only `"eicon-code"` Here is all list:

[Elemetor icons](https://elementor.github.io/elementor-icons/)

For example this code will work:

```
public function get_icon() {
    return 'eicon-code'; 
}
```

Comment: If you have solved your problem you can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Of course. Only after 2 days since I answered.

Comment: Elementor used to support Font Awesome, but they silently removed support about 18 months ago. All of the FA icons I used custom widgets for all past clients no longer show up.

Answer (score 2):

the only way that I found to add a custom icon to the widget is you have to make your font icon(if you don't want to use something like FontAwesome)
and load it to your widget function file. 
 (Tip: if the icon didn't load correctly just add 
 **font-family:"the font family name of your icon" !important** to the icon style file)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the plugin file to load the style(the 4th picture):

```
 <?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: DM Template Elementor Widget
 * Plugin URI: Plugin Author Link
 * Author: Plugin Author Name
 * Author URI: Plugin Author Link
 * Description: This plugin does wonders
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * License: 0.1.0
 * License URL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * text-domain: prefix-plugin-name
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

function my_plugin_frontend_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'frontend-style-1', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'frontend-style-1' );
}

add_action( 'elementor/editor/after_enqueue_styles', 'my_plugin_frontend_stylesheets' );


/**
 * Register  Widget.
 *
 * Include widget file and register widget class.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param \Elementor\Widgets_Manager $widgets_manager Elementor widgets manager.
 * @return void
 */

function register_dm_template_widget($widgets_manager) {

    require_once(__DIR__ . '/widgets/dm-hero-widget.php');

    $widgets_manager->register(new \dm_template_hero_widget());
}
add_action('elementor/widgets/register', 'register_dm_template_widget');
```

Comment: This is the right answer.